# Image to OCR processing using PySpark

Tags: ocr

I am trying to extract text from an image (using pytesser->Tesseract ocr engine) from pyspark, I have uploaded my image file in hdfs and trying to read from spark.

this is my code

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/home/dsuser/Downloads/pytesser")
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from pytesser import *
>>> image_file = 'hdfs://localhost:9000/image/image6.jpg'
>>> rdd = sc.binaryFiles(image_file)
>>> img = Image.open(rdd.first())
>>> text = image_to_string(img)
>>> print("=====output=======\n")
>>> print(text)
```

while running, spark able to load the image file from hdfs, but i am getting below error while calling the below code

```
>>> im = Image.open(rdd.first())
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line
>   2000, in open
>       prefix = fp.read(16) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

not sure about the error, I need help here to convert the image to OCR

Comment: did you try Image.open('file in your HD') to see if it works?